# PayPal sand box equal URL

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Is that

```
ssl://www.paypal.com
```

equal to that

```
ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com
```

but the second is only for the sandbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
This also applies to the API endpoints; they are prefixed with 'sandbox' before 'paypal.com'.
E.g. https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp vs https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

Comment: Thanks a lot McGeek. I just was very confused and also I can't get with PayPal API documentation. I think is very complex :(